# unable to see file in PHP directory

Tags: php, wordpress, file-handling

I am saving a file on my server through file handling like this

```
$my_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-content/themes/mythemev2.0/'.$name.'.php';
echo $my_file;
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);

fwrite($handle, $res->name);
```

`$my_file perfectly` shows me the complete path of the file. But when I go to the particular directory I am unable to see the file. What could be the error? What else can I do for debugging ?

Comment: Have you checked your error log?

Comment: are you calling fclose()?

Comment: Please show the error log of apache...

Comment: @periklis no I am not calling it..

Comment: $handle is not boolean. Use `is_resource()` to check it.

Comment: @periklis calling fclose solved my problem... Please add it as answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're calling fclose() after fwrite()